# Error when using ListView builder in Flutter: Expected a value of type '(Object) => Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I'm encountering an issue while working with my Flutter code. I'm trying to implement a ListView builder within a custom widget, but I'm getting an error message that says: 'Expected a value of type '(Object) => Widget', but got one of type '(String) => SizedBox'. Despite my attempts to adjust the function types, the error persists.

I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter application when using a ListView builder within a custom widget. The error message I'm receiving is: "Expected a value of type '(Object) => Widget', but got one of type '(String) => SizedBox'." I've provided the code below to illustrate the problem. I've tried adjusting the types of functions, but the error persists. Could someone please help me understand and resolve this issue?

```
  const ContentDesktopAdminView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final colors = context.colors;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: max(560, 560),
              width: 1000,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    AnyPage(
                      articles: [
                        Article(
                          lastModified: DateTime.now(),
                          name: 'Something',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}




class ListViewColumn<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListViewColumn({
    required this.itemList,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<ListModel<T>> itemList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            ...itemList.map(
              (e) => Column(
                children: [
                  if (e.columnHeaderCell != null)
                    e.columnHeaderCell!(e.columnName ?? '')
                  else
                    Text(e.columnName ?? ''),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 100.pw,
                    height: 100.pw,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: e.list.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                          e.cell(e.list[index]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ListModel<T> {
  ListModel({
    required this.list,
    required this.cell,
    this.columnName,
    this.columnHeaderCell,
  });

  final String? columnName;
  final List<T> list;
  final Widget Function(T value) cell;
  final Widget Function(String value)? columnHeaderCell;
}

class AnyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnyPage({required this.articles, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Article> articles;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListViewColumn(
      itemList: [
        ListModel(
          list: articles.map((e) => e.name).toList(),
          columnName: 'Title',
          cell: (value) => SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            width: 100,
            child: Text(value),
          ),
        ),
        ListModel(
          list: articles.map((e) => e.lastModified).toList(),
          columnName: 'Last modified',
          cell: (value) => SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            width: 100,
            child: Text(value.toIso8601String()),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Article {
  Article({
    required this.lastModified,
    required this.name,
  });

  final String name;
  final DateTime lastModified;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Stacktrace**:

the generic type of the two `ListModel` widgets in the `itemList` are **different** (one being `String` and the other is `DateTime`), hence the generic type of `ListViewColumn` will be `Object` which in its turn will enforce it's child `itemList` to be `List<ListModel<Object>>` and the `cell` function will be `Widget Function(Object value) cell` and that's the problem, since you can't bind a Widget `Function(<String> or <DateTime>)` to a `Widget Function(Object)`

**easy solution**:

just remove all generic types (aka `<T>`), and use `Widget Function(dynamic value) cell`

**hard solution (but recommended)**:

refactor you code so that `itemList` wont take different generic type, since that is the root of the problem

Answer (score -1):

Seems in the first place article is a class and you are trying to achieve a list view by hand. If you are trying to create a listview, use ListView.builder widget instead. You can check all types of listviews available here

[Listview types](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjw3JanBhCPARIsAJpXTx5HdDFdcKXeGOle0YXxOxV3bMgA28jo8CJZewRvHsktSRk3fAFl_e8aAiKtEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Assuming you can define a list of articles you may want to use something like this.

```
ListView.builder(
            itemCount: articles.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               return MyCustomArticleWidget(article: articles[index]);
            },
);
```

As you can see I'm accessing each of the items and passing the article down MyCustomArticleWidget which is a widget that takes an article as parameter. You can define the stateless widget like this

```
class MyCustomArticleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
final Article article;

const MyCustomArticleWidget({
super.key,
required this.article,
});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Text(article.name); 
  }
}
```